# DotNetNuke: Updating users password in DNN database with custom module

Tags: dotnetnuke

I'm very new to DotNetNuke but I'm creating a custom module where a user can update their details which will then be saved. One of these things is the password. I dont know the best way to insert something into the DotNetNuke database or which table the password is stored in. Can anyone help me with this?

Thanks

EDIT: I've noticed a "ChangePassword" function under the UserController class which would sound like it would do the trick, however its asking for the old password of the user which I don't know how to get

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have had success getting and updating a user's password using the following code.

```
strUsername = Entities.Users.UserController.GetCurrentUserInfo.Username    
strPassword = Membership.Provider.GetPassword(strUsername, String.Empty)
Membership.Provider.ChangePassword(strUsername, strPassword, txtPassword.Text)
```

Comment: This will work as long as the passwords are encrypted (the default) and not hashed (recommended).  Once the passwords are hashed it is no longer possible to look up the current password.

Comment: I can't imagine the passwords will be changed from the default encryption, so this code will fit my needs. Thanks for your help

Comment: Your welcome. I figured I would share because it was a pain figuring this out.

Comment: Dotnetnuke 7 now defaults to hashed passwords instead of encrypted. You can change that in web.config though.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to know the old password, use

```
MembershipProvider.Instance().ResetAndChangePassword(user, "password");
```

where user is UserInfo type object of your user, "password" is the string with new password.
It works in dnn 7.